# Using pickadate.js with Highcharts - event binding problem

Tags: highcharts, pickadate

I am trying to use pickadate.js with highcharts.

It does work, but it requires clicking twice. It looks like highcharts first renders the date in a text svg element and there is accompanying input element that is 1px x 1px. When you click on the text SVG, it is replaced by the input element. Then you click again, and the pickadate opens.

I have tried binding pickadate to the g/text element via $(g.highcharts-range-input).pickadate(), but that doesn't work.

I have also tried using the input.onFocus event to trigger an input.onClick event, which works but then sometimes it goes through two click cycles- causing pickadate to open then immediately close:

```
$('input.highcharts-range-selector').bind("focus", function() {
                console.log("focus");
                $('input.highcharts-range-selector').trigger("click");
});
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/04svbnfd/

Thanks
Matt

Comment: According to the `pickadate.js` documentation, the pickadate component must be attached to the input element - https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ meanwhile input elements in highcharts occurs only after click the first time on the data selector. Have you considered creating a custom inputs for your needs?

Comment: I hadn't considered a custom input. I'm not sure how I would apply that to the problem. I think with some trial and error I can get it to work with my original attempt at binding the input.focus to generate an input.click. I just need an extra step to check if the pickadate is already open.